# How to get correct value from database mysql in php?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a database mysql where I have some string that have this character: "§§STRING§§".
So I do this:

```
$string = explode(§§, $app);
```

Probably mysql have a different format because this string isn't exploded.
What I have to do?

Edit: I catch data from database. $app is a variable created with $row['column']. HOw can I explode?

Comment: Do you see the `§` in your browser or in the DB? If it is in the browser the entity value could be stored in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
$string = explode('§§', $app);
```

Add ''(single quote) for your character.

Comment: You could also use double quotes doesn't matter

Comment: Yes single or double any of your choice.